# Is there a Windows equivalent for the Linux's `vmsplice(2)` syscall?

Tags: linux, windows, system-calls, porting

As per the question title, I'm wondering if Windows has something that is equivalent to Linux's `vmsplice(2)` syscall?

Comment: [`WriteFileGather`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365749) does vectored I/O, but it requires a file opened in asynchronous mode with no caching. You can use overlapped I/O with the named-pipe filesystem, but `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` can't be set via `CreateNamedPipe`. It can be set in a client handle opened with `CreateFile`. I haven't tried `WriteFileGather` in that case, but I'd expect it to work.